NestJs & TypeORM: got DriverPackageNotInstalledError but installed
I'm a newbie in NestJs and TypeORM, please give me some help or tip to solve problem.
In my original NestJs project, I use TypeORM to connect a MariaDB, and I want to connect another MSSQL database at the same time.
I use almost same config code with MariaDB for new connection to MSSQL database; and I had already check the host and login setting correct:
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      name: 'processDB',
      useFactory: () => ({
        name: 'processDB',
        retryAttempts: 10,
        retryDelay: 30 * 1000,
        type: 'mssql',
        host: 'mySQLServerHost,
        port: 1433,
        username: 'myUserName',
        password: 'myPassword',
        database: 'myDatabase',
        entities: ['dist/**/**/processEntities/*{.ts,.js}'],
        synchronize: false,
        maxQueryExecutionTime: 1500,
        logging: ['error'],
        logger: new TypeOrmLogger(true),
        extra: {
          connectionLimit: 30,
          decimalNumbers: true,
        },
        options: {
          encrypt: false,
        },
      }),
    }),

When I build and run the project after append new connection, I got a error as below:
DriverPackageNotInstalledError: SQL Server package has not been found installed. Try to install it: npm install mssql --save
    at SqlServerDriver.loadDependencies (/code/src/driver/sqlserver/SqlServerDriver.ts:1022:19)
    at DriverFactory.create (/code/src/driver/DriverFactory.ts:58:24)
    at new DataSource (/code/src/data-source/DataSource.ts:145:43)
    at createTypeormDataSource (/code/node_modules/@nestjs/typeorm/dist/typeorm-core.module.js:172:23)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/code/node_modules/@nestjs/typeorm/dist/typeorm-core.module.js:176:46)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /code/node_modules/@nestjs/typeorm/dist/typeorm-core.module.js:20:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/code/node_modules/@nestjs/typeorm/dist/typeorm-core.module.js:16:12)

First, I follow as Error information said, run npm install mssql --save.
Then, some topic said need to manually import mssql package, so I add import * as mssql from 'mssql'; in the same file to TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync config code.
But got same DriverPackageNotInstalledError after re build it.
In pachage.json, package-lock.json and node_modules folder, I can found mssql exist.
Thank you for taking the time to read my question.

Although I don't think it's a good solution, the DriverPackageNotInstalledError disappeared after I downgraded mssql to version ^7.0.0.
